# Classifying Multiple Outputs using a Single Neuron

Tags: matlab, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, perceptron

I am a beginner in AI so I am sorry if I ask a dumb question. What I am trying to do is to train only one perceptron to classify some input in 4 classes. I know that, normally, a perceptron is a binary classifier, but I am wondering if I can break the rule for this particular case which has a very easy classification rule. The data sample contains points given by cartesian coordinates. It is given the fact that  x-coordinate will always be an integer between [1, 4] and the y-coordinate will take values between 0 and 1 with only 1 digit precision. ( [0:.1:1] Matlab expression). The classes depends only on X-coordinate. The class is just the X-coordinate. For example (1, 0.3) is in class 1, (3, 0.2) is in class 3. It is possible to train only 1 perceptron to learn this rule? Thanks in advance

Comment: Normally, a perceptron does not give a binary output. The output is used as is for regression tasks and binarized for classification. Also, if the class is just the value of X, then your f(x,y) = x which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @akaya Some do, it depends on the transfer function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, not with a standard binary bipolar threshold perceptron. Unless you have some crazy non-linear perceptron that has logic already built into the transfer function, you will require more neurons to approximate the logic. Keep in mind the more non-linear your transfer function is, the more complex your training will be.

Take the example of the [XOR operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or). Even a simple logic gate such as that will require 2 hidden neurons. [Here's a reference of what I'm talking about for XOR](http://www.heatonresearch.com/online/introduction-neural-networks-java-edition-2/chapter-1/page4.html).

For those questioning what the OP meant by binary perceptron, the OP meant this.

[image: Binary Bipolar Threshold Perceptron]